# Javascript - Quebra de linha em arquivo .txt

Tags: javascript, txt

Como identifico uma quebra de linha em um txt usando javascript ?

Exemplo:

```
Essa é a linha 1
Essa é a linha 2
Essa é a linha 3
```

O arquivo tem essas 3 linhas e quero colocar elas em um array separadas pela quebra de linha, array[0] é a linha 1, array[1] a linha 2, etc...
Lembrando q puxo esses dados de um .txt via ajax...

OBS: É puxado o resultado de um arquivo .txt, ele não tem /n pra pular as linhas e sim uma quebra de linha feita pressionando a tecla ENTER. O.o

Comment: Não precisa ter \n, esse metacaractere representa uma quedra de linha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo completo de como você pode fazer isso usando Ajax:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'arquivo.txt', true);
xhr.responseType = 'text';

var texto = '';

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {

            texto = xhr.responseText;

            //Pega o resultado da requisição Ajax e à transforma em um array.
            var linhas = texto.split(/\n/);

            //Percorrer linha por linha do arquivo.
            for (var linha in linhas) {
              alert(linhas[linha]);
              //console.log(linhas[linha]);
            }

        }
    }
};

xhr.send(null);
```

arquivo.txt

```
Essa é a linha 1
Essa é a linha 2
Essa é a linha 3
```

Obs.: Não precisa ter \n no arquivo, essa metacaractere representa uma quebra de linha.

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar a função split que ele retorna um array.

```js
var txt = "Essa é a linha 1\nEssa é a linha 2\nEssa é a linha 3";

var vetor = txt.split("\n");

vetor.forEach(function(x) { console.log(x) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
 var valor = "Essa é a linha 1\nEssa é a linha 2\nEssa é a linha 3";
 if (/[\n|\n\r]/.test(valor))
 {
   alert("Existem quebras de linha!");
 } 
 else
 {
   alert("Não existem quebras de linha!");
 }
```